# When is Cov(A, B) = VarA?

Tags: probability, statistics

This is the problem I am trying to solve:

A penny which is unbalanced so that the probability of heads is 0.4 is tossed twice. Let Z be the number of heads obtained in the first toss. Let W be the total number of heads obtained in the two tosses of the coin.

a)  Calculate the correlation coefficient between Z and W

b)  Show numerically that Cov(Z, W) = VarZ

c)  Show without using numbers that Cov(Z, W) = VarZ

I am stuck on part (c): given that Cov(Z, W)=E[(Z-E(Z))(W-E(W)] and VarZ=E[(Z-E(Z))^2], it looks like I should establish the relationship W-E(W) = Z-E(Z) for the above to be true.
Is it the way to go?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

No.

**Hint:** Let $Y$ be the count for heads in the second toss, so that $Y$ and $Z$ are *independent and identically* distributed, and that $W=Z+Y$.   Now apply the Bilinearity of Covariance.